# App on MAS that writes mathematical formulae into an image?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I remember an app that was featured on the Mac App Store a while ago that allows you to write mathematical formulae into an image.

I can't find it now though. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: how do you want to write the formula? with keyboard (latex format) or with a mouse/trackpad?

Comment: Mouse/trackpad would be great. I've actually found out that it is Brisk, but is there an app that does this without using LaTex, with a mouse/trackpad?

Comment: You would be better placed accepting the answer and asking this as a new question, to help future searchers benefit from a more focused question & answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out "Brisk", MAS link and screenshots etc here: http://www.chocomoko.com/brisk, Youtube screencast demo here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVeJ4_DErX0

Answer (score 4):

It isn't in the Mac App Store, but try [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en).

As you might have guessed, it uses Latex input to create an image of the equation.  You can link the image into a Keynote or Pages document (or others, I'd imagine).  Live updating, etc.

I use it frequently, and love it!

Comment: Note that you need to be familiar with LaTeX to use this app. That said, this is a spectacular application... it can export as png or pdf, many customizable options, keeps history of previous equations, and other stuff. I relied on this app for all of my presentations during my graduate (and postgraduate) career.